# WebView2 with arguments and without arguments

Tags: vb.net, winforms, arguments, webview2, navigateurl

I'm trying to start two WebView2 browsers.

1 with arguments and 1 without arguments.

But i can't get it to work, i get a error with:
WebView_Browser2.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.google.nl/")

> Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2.CoreWebView2.get returned Nothing.

This is the code i have so far.

```
 Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

 Await InitializeAsync()

 End Sub

 Private Async Function InitializeAsync() As Task

 Dim opts As New CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions With {.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--kiosk-printing"}
 Dim env = Await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(Nothing, Nothing, opts)

 Await WebView_Browser1.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()
 Await WebView_Browser2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env)

 AddHandler WebView_Browser1.CoreWebView2.FrameNavigationCompleted, AddressOf WebView_Browser1_FrameNavigationCompleted
 AddHandler WebView_Browser2.CoreWebView2.FrameNavigationCompleted, AddressOf WebView_Browser2_FrameNavigationCompleted

 End Function

 Private Sub WV_CoreWebView2Ready1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WebView_Browser1.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted

 WebView_Browser1.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.google.nl/")

 End Sub

 Private Sub WV_CoreWebView2Ready2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WebView_Browser2.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted

 WebView_Browser2.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.google.nl/")

 End Sub
```

If i start both Await WebView_Browser1.EnsureCoreWebView2Async() with 'env' arguments they work.

But i would like to start 1 with and without arguments.
Thank you for your time!

**UPDATE**

When i create two seperate CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync using no arguments i get the same error.
If i change the Arguments to something else i get the error.
But when i use the exact same arguments .AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--kiosk-printing"} it works.
Maybe you can't start two WebView2 browsers on one form with different or one with and one without arguments?

Comment: Can you call `CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync` twice to create two different environments: one with the additional arguments and one without?

Comment: Sadly no. I get the same error.